# Power of Double - Logarithmic Space

Tags: complexity-theory, space-complexity

I try to solve exercise "on the power of double - logarithmic space" from the great textbook [Computational Complexity by Oded Goldreich.](http://books.google.com/books?id=EuguvA-w5OEC&pg=PA176&lpg=PA176&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) 
The goal is to show that the given set $S=\left \{ w_k \mid k \in \mathbb{N} \right \}$, where $w_k$ - concatenation of all $k$-bit long strings separated by *'s is not regular and yet it is decidable in double-logarithmic space. The exercise contains guidelines, and I would like to shed the light on few sentences from guidelines in order to solve the exercise.

In the guidelines it's mentioned that

> we can take advantage of of the *'s (in $w_i$) , the $i$th iteration
>   can be implemented in space $O(\log i)$

The $i$th iteration is verifying whether $x = w_i$, which is really can be decided in $O(\log i)$ space, where $\log i$ can be used to note the position in $i$ long string, but the position in $x$ can be included in $O(\log i)$ or not?

> Furthermore, on input $x \notin S$, we halt and reject after at most
>   $\log |x|$ iterations.

It means only $\log |x|$ $w$'s from the set S will be compared to $x$. Why it is actually so?

> Actually, it is slightly simpler to handle the related set
>   $\left \{w_1**w_2**..**w_k \right \}$

Why it is actually so, and I would call it set, it is rather concatenated string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the set $\left \{w_1**w_2**..**w_k \right \}$ contains only one single element, but is nevertheless a set. And TM can accept only languages, which are sets of words.

Why is it slightly easier? Hmm, I would say, it is easier since you can simplify the algorithm **slightly**. You have one counter for $k$, and then you check, whether in the string $\cdots *x*y*\cdots$, you have $\text{bin}(y)=\text{bin}(x)+1$ on every position. You do not have to care about detecting the right $k$. Other than this, the suoer-string is longer, which gives you more space. But this effect vanishes in the big-O.